# Laravel eloquant collection - unable to convert it to valid json

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have one laravel eloquant object which i want to convert to JSON to store in MySQL database, i am using below code to convert

```
Order::create(['product' => json_encode($cart->product, true)]);
```

I also tried below

```
Order::create(['product' => $cart->product->toJson()]);
```

This code is storing perfectly but with seems invalid json format like below

```
"{\"id\": 5,\"name\": \"CAPSTER CAP\",\"description\": \"This is the\"}"
```

but it should be like below

```
{"id": 5,"name": "CAPSTER CAP","description": "This is the"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to create a text or longText datatype column in MySQL database.
Then save JSON as a string like this.

```
Order::create(['product' => json_encode($cart->product->toArray()) ]);
```

Comment: Hii
i tried your solution but the same issue, i have longText datatype in the database

Comment: Get data from table and use json_decode(), if it returns a valid JSON then ignore back slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your migration class's structure. Use json data type for the model class e.g

```
 Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->json('product')->nullable();
     $table->timestamps();
 });
```

Comment: Hi Brian, yes i tried with this method too, but still same issue

Comment: Even with this defined in your controller class : ` $data = json_encode($request->product);
     Order::create($data);`

Comment: Nope, i checked if i remove " from beginning and ending then it works